# Apache modrewrite .htaccess - similar link

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am wondering if it is possible to achieve this bellow:

Sometimes second attribute will be submenu

```
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?menu=$1&submenu=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Sometimes it will be location

```
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?menu=$1&news=$2 [L,QSA]
```

But normally, this way it does not work. Is there any possible way to achieve this?

**EDIT:**
Current complete rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
ErrorDocument 404 /error

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]


RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?menu=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?menu=$1&news=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?menu=$1&submenu=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?menu=$1&submenu=$2&news=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: You should post the complete rewrite rules list. For example having a RewriteBase directive could change the overall behavior.

Comment: Surely it won't work this way. You need to prefix `news` link as: `/main/n-top` => `/index.php?menu=main&news=top`

Comment: Can you be more exact please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To elaborate on my comment further you can have rules like this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /error
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?menu=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/n-([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?menu=$1&news=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?menu=$1&submenu=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?menu=$1&submenu=$2&news=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Now your news links should like this: `http://domain.com/main-menu/n-sports`

Comment: This seems to be working now. Thanks.
Although I do not understand this perfectlly, what this "n-" does :)

Comment: You're welcome. `n-` is there as a prefix in your news link so that you don't have exactly same matching pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Consider that your regex starts matching `\w`, which stands for "word character", usually `[A-Za-z0-9_]`. Notice the inclusion of the underscore and digits. This also means that this doesn't match accented characters for example. For sure this don't match the leading slash that begins every path in urls.

You should change your rewrites adding a leading slash:

```
RewriteRule ^/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?menu=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?menu=$1&news=$2 [L,QSA]

# RewriteRule ^/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?menu=$1&submenu=$2 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?menu=$1&submenu=$2&news=$3 [L,QSA]
```

I have also commented the third rule because the regex is identical to the second. Your approach also have a logical problem, since there is no difference between these lines, so there is no way to call `index.php?menu=$1&submenu=$2`